# Correr un script de Python desde PHP sin esperar respuesta

Tags: php, python, script, backgroundworker

Mi problema es que tengo una pagina WEB que debo integrar a un Bot en python para cada usuario y hacer un llamado al bot de python y que se quede corriendo en el servidor aun cuando el usuario se haya desconectado.

he intentado hacerlo con la funcion shell_exec desde PHP pero se queda colgado PHP esperando una respuesta.

Debo ejecutar el script python en el servidor desde PHP el cual genera una respuesta que es almacenada en la base de datos desde python.

actualmente corro el bot manualmente en el servidor con la funcion "screen" para que quede corriendo en el background. pero quiero automatizar el proceso a que sea corrido al pulsar un boton en mi Pagina WEB

Estoy corriendo en un Entorno Ubuntu Server en Apache2. y en el mismo servidor tengo mi script Python que quiero ejecutar

Answer (score 0):

No especificas el sistema operativo, pero debes abrir un proceso asíncrono con popen(). Suponiendo que estas trabajando con Windows

```
$command = 'start /b python.exe ruta_del_script.py argumentos_si_los_tiene';
pclose(popen($command, 'r'));
```

http://php.net/manual/es/function.popen.php

Comment: Disculpa gracias por la aclaratoria. Pero tengo todo corriendo en Linux Ubuntu Server en AWS